# Can't compile kernel on Ubuntu 22.04.1, dependecy replaces initramfs with tiny-initramfs

Tags: kernel, initramfs

I'm trying to compile a kernel on a brand new Ubuntu 22.04.1.
If I follow the guide in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel I get a scary warning after `make install`:

```
tiny-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.68
/usr/sbin/mktirfs: WARNING: / file system on device mapper, not supported by tiny-initramfs
YOUR SYSTEM WILL NOT BOOT WITH THIS INITRAMFS.
```

I tried replacing it with `sudo apt install initramfs-tools`, but something broke the drivers and I had no network connection after boot.
I started with a clean install again.
It took me a while to find out why tiny-initramfs was being used but I eventually found it:
The `libpci-dev` (and `libudev-dev`) package installs `tiny-initramfs tiny-initramfs-core`, which breaks the kernel installation.

Here's the output of apt:

[image]

What's the correct approach here? I did not have this issue in ubuntu 20, should I just go back to it?

edit: Things are more complicated, it seems. Installing `libudev-dev` nukes the system, removing a lot of essential packages. I posted a question on ubuntu and I'll report back if I find an answer.

Comment: Fixed the naming.

Answer (score 0):

Found out this is a bug in Ubuntu. Don't install `libudev-dev` in Ubuntu 22.04.1 through apt for now. Manual download and install is fine.

More information here:  https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+question/703310